# NLTK: How to fetch information from text files based on user input?

Tags: python, nltk

Hi I'm working on NLTK with Python(version 3.4) to develop a QA system on medical domain which takes in user query in the form of a question and processes it to give the relevant answer.
For example, a user may enter: What is Arthritis? or Who is the best doctor for cancer?

I have my data stored in text files, like I have a text file Arthritis in folder named **definitions** and list of doctors in folder named **doctors**. Hence in case of Who is the best doctor for cancer I need to search the cancer file in **doctors** folder and display the information stored in it. The user can also enter Who is the best physician for cancer? Hence I have also computed the synonyms of the nouns in the question input by user.
The code I've written is:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

stopset = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
sentence = input("Enter query:\n")
sent_words = word_tokenize(sentence)
tokens = [w for w in sent_words if not w in stopset]
tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())
nouns = [word for word,pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NN' or pos=='NNP' or pos== 'NNS' or pos== 'NNPS']
lower_nouns = [nn.lower() for nn in nouns]
synonyms = []

for wt in lower_nouns:
  for syn in wn.synsets(wt):
      for l in syn.lemmas():
          set_syn = synonyms.append(l.name())
```

What should I add or modify in my code to do the above stated task of retrieving information from respected folders based on user query as it only computes the synonyms as of now and does not fetch information from text files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, then maybe you could try something like the following: provided you have two categories, doctors and definitions, the related_terms could be `related_terms = [['doctor', 'some synonym for doctor', 'another synonym', ...], ['definition', 'some_synonym', 'maybe the term arthritis here or any other term that would help you navigate to the correct information?', ... ]]`.

```
    stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    sentence = input("Enter query:\n")
    sent_words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    tokens = [w for w in sent_words if not w in stopset]
    tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())
    nouns = [word for word, pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS']
    lower_nouns = [nn.lower() for nn in nouns]
    synonyms = []
    categories = ["doctors", "definitions"]
    categories_folder_paths = ["path to doctors", "path to definitions"]
    related_terms = [['synonyms for doctors'], ['synonyms for definitions']]

    for wt in lower_nouns:
        for syn in wn.synsets(wt):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(l.name())

    # find out which category has the most common synonyms with the terms your user asked
    doctors_intersect = list(set(synonyms).intersection(set(related_terms[categories.index("doctor")])))
    definitions_intersect = list(set(synonyms).intersection(set(related_terms[categories.index("definitions")])))

    # the length of the results should indicate with which category the query matches most
    if len(doctors_intersect) > len(definitions_intersect):
        # check the doctors folder with similar logic as above in order to use e.g. the cancer's file.
        pass
    elif len(doctors_intersect) < len(definitions_intersect):
        # check the definitions folder with similar logic as above in order to use e.g. the arthritis' file.
        pass

    else:
        print "I didn't get that, did you mean.... ?"
        # and try again?
```

Hope this helps, but I must say it all depends on how you have structured your data and your categories.

P.S.: For this task I would try classification, having for example the categories as 'doctor', 'definition' and the content of the respective data as the train/test set maybe as a simple bag of words model. But I cannot say more without knowing what your data is and generally knowing specifics.

Good luck!

**Edit:**

This is one very basic working example of how you can do this. I have used a custom pos tag model that works well on short text and a lemmatizer. The model loaded is this https://bitbucket.org/mkaranasou/figurative-text-analysis/raw/c804fd3163d8682da2f1ab69095600de296eae56/figurative-text-analysis/TweetUtils/data/model_dict.txt

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


def q_and_a():
    stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    sentence = raw_input("Enter query:\n")
    sent_words = word_tokenize(sentence)
    tokens = [w for w in sent_words if not w in stopset]
    # tagged_sent = pos_tag(sentence.split())
    tagged_sent = get_custom_pos_tags(sentence.split())
    nouns = [word for word, pos in tagged_sent if pos == 'NN' or pos == 'NNP' or pos == 'NNS' or pos == 'NNPS']
    lower_nouns = [nn.lower() for nn in nouns]
    synonyms = []
    lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()  # lemmatize / stem for better results

    # terms should be the terms of interest along with their synonyms
    terms = [
        ['cancer', 'carcenogenic'],
        ['fever', 'feverish', 'temperature'],
        ['cancer', 'carcenogenic', 'doctor', 'therapist', 'professional']
    ]
    path_to_terms = ["../data/cancer.txt", "../data/fever.txt", "../data/cancer_doctors.txt"]

    # a good idea would be to stem synonyms
    for wt in lower_nouns:
        for syn in wn.synsets(wt):
            for l in syn.lemmas():
                synonyms.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(l.name()))
        synonyms.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(wt))  # include the original

    results = []
    for each in terms:
        results.append(get_similarity(synonyms, each))

    max_sim = max(results)  # note: there could be two results with the same percentage

    if max_sim >= 20:  # some threshold
        with open(path_to_terms[results.index(max_sim)]) as f:
            print " ".join(f.readlines())
    else:
        print "I couldn't find something regarding: '%s'" % sentence


def get_similarity(input_terms, category_terms):
    input_set = set(input_terms)
    category_set = set(category_terms)
    common = input_set.intersection(category_set)

    # how many from the category did we get right
    return (len(common) / float(len(category_set))) * 100


def get_custom_pos_tags(word_list):
    """
        Get pos tagging results using custom tagger with the model provided by gate twitter tagger.
        Reference: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/twitter-postagger.html
        L. Derczynski, A. Ritter, S. Clarke, and K. Bontcheva, 2013: "Twitter
        Part-of-Speech Tagging for All: Overcoming Sparse and Noisy Data". In:
        Proceedings of the International Conference on Recent Advances in Natural
        Language Processing.
    """
    # use a custom model that works well on short text
    default_tagger = nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER)
    train_model = g.train_model  # custom gate model
    tagger = nltk.tag.UnigramTagger(model=train_model, backoff=default_tagger)
    return tagger.tag(word_list)
```

The way the custom model is loaded like this:

```
def _prepare_gate_pos_tags_model(self):
    # stored processed model as a dict in file so to minimize load time
    with open('path to/model_dict.txt', 'r') as f:
        train_model = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

Example output:

```
C:\Python27_32b\python.exe C:/Users/m.karanasou/Documents/figurative-text-analysis/figurative-text-analysis/FigurativeTextAnalysis/helpers/test_snippets.py
Enter query:
Show me about fever
Details about fever....


C:\Python27_32b\python.exe C:/Users/m.karanasou/Documents/figurative-text-analysis/figurative-text-analysis/FigurativeTextAnalysis/helpers/test_snippets.py
Enter query:
Tell me about doctors for cancer.
Doctor A name, surname, contact details
 Doctor B name, surname, contact details

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I hope this helps a bit. It obviously doesn't work well in all cases but you see my point. There are many ways and 'configurations' that will help you do this.

Comment: Yes you're right, there are two categories definitions and doctors. But these categories and their respective folders will be accessed based on user input question. Say the user enters: What is cancer? Hence I need a definition as output and will have to look in definitions folder under cancer.txt (definitions/cancer.txt) or else the user could have asked Who is the best doctor for fever and then in that case I'll have to look into doctors folder under fever.txt for name of doctors for fever. 

Hope this makes sense now.

Comment: Further help on this will be highly appreciated.